# How to build crash kernel for my new kernel?

Tags: linux, crash, linux-kernel

I am trying to collect kernel crash core for my own custom kernel. So far, I have not been able to.

I see that there is a special 'kdump' kernel associated with the original that came with the distro (i.e., CentOS 7):

```
[hebbo@localhost boot]$ ls -l *3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   152976 Aug  7 14:11 config-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
-rw-------. 1 root root 31818213 Dec  9 15:39 initramfs-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64.img
-rw-------. 1 root root 13775124 Dec 10 00:23 initramfs-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64kdump.img
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   318717 Aug  7 14:12 symvers-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root  3594971 Aug  7 14:11 System.map-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  6734016 Aug  7 14:12 vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
```

I mean exactly the file initramfs-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64kdump.img . How do I generate one like this for my own custom kernel?

Thanks.